# iOS SMS and Call Spam Reporting extension is reporting the wrong number

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sms

I am new to iOS and I'm facing an issue with the SMS and Call spam reporting extension for iOS 14.6. I've implemented the extension and when I select one or more messages and click the button to report the sender, the sender's phone number is getting reported, but with a string appended to its number. For example:
[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMHqX.png)

The numbers that should be displayed are "orange" and "+40 753878811", but instead "filtered" is appended to every number. In this case, the numbers are not actually blocked and I am still able to receive messages and calls from them.

Any meaningful piece of code that I use is in the classificationResponse method:

```
override func classificationResponse(for request:ILClassificationRequest) -> ILClassificationResponse {

    return ILClassificationResponse(action: .reportJunkAndBlockSender)

}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is to block any user that I click on, either from the messages app or from the contacts.

Does anybody know why is this happening?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code.  In particular the code that is producing the output in your screenshot.

Comment: But where is that screen shot taken from?  Is it produced by your code?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, I enable the extension, go to the inbox, select one or more messages and press the button for reporting. The interface of the extension is displayed and after I press _Done_ I go into settings and expect to find the sender of the messages that i reported, but instead I find what's in the screenshot.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an entry in your contacts for that number with the name "+40 753878811filtered"?  I created a bare-bones call blocking extension and don't see the issue you are describing.  I did note that if you block a number that is in your contacts then it shows the name of the contact, not the number or do you have unknown contact filtering enabled?

Comment: @Paulw11 I was also using a message filter extension and I was trying to report the number from the junk folder (where the messages were filtered). If I report the number from the inbox or another place it's working fine. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: Is there way to report SMS and call without doing manually?